# React Unknown Prop 'onSearch'

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, input, autocomplete

I'm trying to use [onSearch](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsearch.asp) event on a search input like this:

```
render(){
  return(

  <input type="search" onSearch={ () => console.warn('search') }  />
  );
}
```

But I get the [unknown prop error](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html), any ideas of how to fix it?

I want to create a autocomplete input that fires an event when the user clicks on the "search" icon in the keyboard.

**EDIT:**

onSearch is not an standard attribute so I guess react wont support it. Since onSearch is the same as hitting enter key, using onKeypress will do the job:

```
render() {
  return (
    <main>
      <input onKeyPress={ this.onKeyPress } type="search" list="options"/>
      <datalist id="options">
        { OPTS.map(item => <option value={ item.nm } key={ item.id } data-id={ item.id } />) }
      </datalist>
    </main>
    );
  }


onKeyPress(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    const id = document.querySelector(`#options   option[value="${event.target.value}"]`).dataset.id;
    if (id) {
      console.warn('user search', id);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using `onSubmit` or `onChange` instead of `onSearch`.

Answer (score 5):

`search` is absolutely a DOM event of search type `input` but react doesn't support it yet.
so you may listen to raw dom element events.

do like this

```
<Input
  ref={element=>(element||{}).onsearch=this.searchHandler}
/>
```

this can work, you may want to know why.

First, `ref` attribute accept a function as a value, which will be executed with a real dom element(opposite to virtual dom).

And before the real dom be mounted to document the function will be executed too, but there's no element we can attach an event to, so we use `(element||{})` to avoid errors.

Instead of using `addEventListener`, we use `ele.onsearch` way, because the component will rerender when props or state update, each time the render function be called we will attach an event to the dom element when `search` event fired the handler function can be run several times.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `onChange`. An input will fire a change event when you edit the data inside it.

EDIT:
`onSearch` is not supported by React [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html) you can use a keypress event or keyup event to do the same thing. just check the keycode and see if its an enter (13)

```
handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        console.warn('search');
    }
}

<input type="search" onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
```

Comment: Nope, onchange is fired each time the user writes something in my input i want the event to be fired only when the user clicks on the "search" icon on the keyboard.

Comment: @lagoLast Ah I see what you're saying. I can edit my answer to show how to use onChange to work for onSubmit if you'd like

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work:

```
constructor() {
  this.state = { userInput: "" };

  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit() {  
    console.warn('user search', this.state.userInput);
}

render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>       
      <input 
        onChange={e => this.setState({userInput: e.target.value})} 
        type="search" 
        list="options" 
        value={this.state.userInput}
      />
      <datalist id="options">
        { OPTS.map(item => <option value={ item.nm } key={ item.id } data-id={ item.id } />) }
      </datalist>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Take a look at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html. You probably want to use controlled components instead of accessing the DOM directly to get the input value.